# android listactivity MenuItemCompat.getActionView always returns null

Tags: android, android-appcompat, searchview

I have created activity extended ListActivity.
In Actionbar i haved added action bar searchview.

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView|withText"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

It works fine, but my issue is i can not find search view in method

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    ....

    // SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
       SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search));
```

"searchView" always return null.

But if i used this

```
android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView
```

it works fine.

My requirement is i must use MenuItemCompat and catch onQueryTextSubmit event in same activity instead of searchable activity.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search_user)
            .getActionView();


    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

@Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(final String query) {

-------


}
```

Comment: first, i am using app:actionViewClass in search menu. Secondly my activity is extended by ListActivity not ActionBarActivity and i doesn't allow to use searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this); directly.

Comment: i tried the above code snippet. Its not working and searchview is null.

Comment: A straight question is, can we use MenuItemCompat in Activity that is extended by ListActivity not ActionBarActivity ?

Comment: i am use extends AppCompatActivity and it's work for me .. i dont know how use with listactivity ..
http://oi58.tinypic.com/2zrn8k2.jpg